# Convert args to flat list?

Tags: python, list

I know this is very *similar* to a few other questions, but I can't quite get this function to work correctly.

```
def flatten(*args):
    return list(item for iterable in args for item in iterable)
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
flatten(1) -> [1]
flatten(1,[2]) -> [1, 2]
flatten([1,[2]]) -> [1, 2]
```

The current function, which I took from another SO answer, doesn't seem to produce correct results at all:

```
>>> flatten([1,[2]])
[1, [2]]
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, and accept that one. Keeps the site cleaner :)

Comment: I updated my answer, too - your self-found answer was a little neater. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a quick solution, just take your second function and make it recursive.

```
def flatten(*args):
    output = []
    for arg in args:
        if hasattr(arg, '__iter__'):
            output.extend(flatten(*arg))
        else:
            output.append(arg)
    return output
```

Comment: Sample for strange dictionary results:

    >>> def flatten(*args):
    ...     output = []
    ...     for arg in args:
    ...         if hasattr(arg, '__iter__'):
    ...             output.extend(flatten(*arg))
    ...         else:
    ...             output.append(arg)
    ...     return output
    ...
    >>> adict = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
    >>> blist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    >>> raw = [adict, blist]
    >>> flatten(raw)
    [1, 3, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: Iterating over a dictionary yields it's keys. Since the original question didn't say anything about the desired output for dictionaries, why is this output strange?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to flatten arbitrarily nested lists you need a recursive function:

```
def flatten(ls):
  if isinstance(ls, list):
     return [fa for a in ls for fa in flatten(a)]
  else:
     return [ls]
```

(If you expect to flatten big structures this could be made more efficient by using generators instead of returning lists.)

This function can also be reused to create a function that takes multiple parameters:

```
def pflatten(*ls):
   return flatten(list(ls))
```

Comment: The input argument should be `*ls`. That does make a difference, doesn't it? And `hasattr(a, '__iter__')` is slightly more versatile than `isinstance` isn't it?

Comment: @Mark: Currently the function takes one argument, and if it's a list, it flattens it. It could also be done with `*ls`, so that the function takes several parameters and creates a flat list of their concatenations. What interface you prefer is just a matter of taste, I'd say. Similar for `isinstance(a, list)` vs. `hasattr(a, '__iter__')`: It just depends what kind of result you want when you give it a list of lists of sets. A list of sets or a list of all the elements in all the sets? Depending on your requirements one or the other would be preferable.

Comment: Well yes, but this question was specifically about the latter (`*ls`). I see your point about sets though... not planning on using those, but tuples should definitely be converted to a flat list.

Comment: @Mark: Oops, you are of course right, the question is about `*ls`... I edited a little additional function into my answer to cover that case :). To also cover tuples, probably the easiest way would be to add `or isinstance(ls, tuple)` to the check in `flatten()`.

Comment: Your `pflatten` doesn't work. Did you try it? I get `pflatten(1,[2]) -> [(1, [2])]` which is the sort of problem I was having when I posted this Q. Don't worry about it tho..... *my* solution does seem to work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Checking **__*iter*__** presence can be quite strange when flattening dictionary:

```py
>>> def flatten(*args):
...     output = []
...     for arg in args:
...         if hasattr(arg, '__iter__'):
...             output.extend(flatten(*arg))
...         else:
...             output.append(arg)
...     return output
...
>>> adict = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
>>> blist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> raw = [adict, blist]
>>> flatten(raw)
[1, 3, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

I think flatten should work for lists and tuples only:

```py
import types

def flatten(*args):
    output = []
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, (types.ListType, types.TupleType)):
            output.extend(flatten(*list(arg)))
        else:
            output.append(arg)
    return output

adict = {1:2, 3:4, 5:6}
blist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
raw = [adict, blist]
print flatten(raw)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved it...

```
def flatlist(*args):
    lst = []
    for a in args:
        if hasattr(a, '__iter__'): lst.extend(flatlist(*a))
        else: lst.append(a)
    return lst
```